# Iteration using python

Tags: python

Hi I would like create some code which will print a box that looks like this

```
 + -- + -- + -- + -- + -- +
 |    |    |    |    |    |
 + -- + -- + -- + -- + -- +
```

The code should use a loop to print a row of boxes using for i in range(5)(**There should be no use of IF statement to solve this problem)** by using one box only as shown below

```
+ -- +
|    |
+ -- +
```

I have attempted to use the code below but not producing the output required. Please help

```
for i in range(5):
    print("+--+\n|  |\n+--+", end=" ")
```

Comment: sounds like a homework problem

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate to post problems you encounter during homework on StackOverflow, however, you haven't run into a problem here, you just haven't tried to implement it yet. Try it, and when you have a specific problem, come back and ask about it.

Comment: Why did you re-post the exact same question that you already accepted an answer to 3 hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to print each individual line before you use a `\n` character. I will not give you the answer, but I will give you a structure to help point you in the right direction.

```
l1 = "+"
l2 = "|"
for i in range(5):
    #add chunk into l1
    #add chunk into l2

#print the compiled lines in the correct order to show the boxes
```